# How to programmatically load a python script in Text Editor and launch it

Tags: python

With python API, is it possible to load a (new) python script in the Text Editor and then launch it (to automate things !) ?

I try this but it doesn't work :

```
bpy.ops.text.open(filepath="my-script.py")
bpy.ops.text.run_script()
```

Script name added in the text list but not visible in the Editor.

Comment: Where are you running this from?

Comment: From command line : $ blender.exe --python script-to-automate-things.py

Comment: My configuration : Blender version 2.69, OS Cygwin on Windows7

Comment: I must add that i just try to simplify the task for my project. Everything loaded and executed and the script ready to be completed in the text editor.

Answer (score 10):

Every Text Editor has its own active (visible) text datablock stored in `.text`.

To call the `text.run_script()` operator, use a context override and give it the right `'edit_text'` member.

```
import bpy

text = bpy.data.texts.load(path_to_file)

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'TEXT_EDITOR':
        area.spaces[0].text = text # make loaded text file visible

        ctx = bpy.context.copy()
        ctx['edit_text'] = text # specify the text datablock to execute
        ctx['area'] = area # not actually needed...
        ctx['region'] = area.regions[-1] # ... just be nice

        bpy.ops.text.run_script(ctx)
        break
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: You can also use ```area.spaces.active.text = text``` since ```area.spaces[0]``` is the active space.

Answer (score 7):

It seems it can be done in less code even, just the following code, no TextEditor windows open.

```
# text = bpy.data.texts.load(path_to_file)   # if from disk
text = bpy.data.texts['some_file_name.py']   # if exists in blend
ctx = bpy.context.copy()
ctx['edit_text'] = text
bpy.ops.text.run_script(ctx)
```

executed fine!

Answer (score 3):

Another technique is illustrated at http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/exec-text-library.html

```
import bpy
bufferName = 'lib 1'
lib1 = bpy.data.texts[bufferName].as_string()
exec(lib1)
```

Comment: this even works when the script being exec'd is importing local datablock .py files as modules. nice.

Comment: this can fail if the file you are trying to exec has a few imports not already present in globals/locals -- and this isn't being executed directly from the TextEditor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessary need to load it. You can use a browser to get the path p
and then run `exec(compile(open(p).read(), p, 'exec'))`. The script will be executed.