# text from updating file

Tags: text-object

I'm learning to use blender in order to get this result:
when I push a button on pygame I'll have a solid, like a stone, appearing from the ground. on this "stone" I would have written a text from a file that changes every time I use this function. I would only ask if it's possible with blender to have this result, or it's better to give up and think something more easy to do?
thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you want the text to be a texture on the stone or can it be a separate text object?

Comment: Is this an animation? Or are you using the BGE?

Comment: @maddin45 - I would have a texture on the stone.

Comment: @gandalf3 - I don't know what is BGE but I would have the stone (or a box) come out the floor and some text printed on it (if possible!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me how this is related to [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) so I focus on this part of your question:

> I would only ask if it's possible with blender to have this result

Yes, you could create an action with two keyframes (start and end position of z coordinate of your cube).

At the right side you see the action "CubeAction" in the *Dope Sheet (set to Action Editor)*
At the bottom a Keyboard Sensor which is active when <kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed and an *Action Controller* which plays the animation stored in the action.

[image]

To dynamically create the text object one idea would be to copy it in the text-editor and use:

```
bpy.ops.text.to_3d_object(split_lines=True)
```

This function is probably not available while the game engine is running
For how to load a text into the editor see: [How to programmatically load a python script in Text Editor and launch it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8435/how-to-programmatically-load-a-python-script-in-text-editor-and-launch-it)

How to port this to pygame isn't on topic here.

Comment: the suggestion for blender is just what I need, thanks. relating to pygame, I still have to verify but I think to use a button to launch my blender animation.