# How do you assign a logic brick onto an indivual bone?

Tags: python, armature

I am trying to make a simple head turn but there are multiple bones that are part of the object for rigging... every time I try to assign a logic brick in edit mode to **only** the bone controlling the turn of the head... it assigns it to every bone making the whole body turn.

Comment: You could keyframe multiple bones in a single action: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12134/text-from-updating-file/12138#12138

Answer (score 2):

Blender's logic bricks are attached to an object. An armature is one object that can contain several bones, a simple motion actuator will move the entire armature as one solid object.

To move a single bone you need to [create an action](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet), then play the action using an [action actuator](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Logic/Actuators/Action).