# Calling bpy.ops.text.save() from '3D_VIEW' operator execute method

Tags: python

A Text Datablock named "Text" exists. Within a 3D View operator, I'm attempting to generate the dialog for writing this Datablock to a file, where the user can select a folder and choose a filename. In my 3D View operator, I have:

```
def execute(self, context):
    area_type = bpy.context.area.type
    bpy.context.area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
    context.space_data.text = bpy.data.texts["Text"]
    bpy.ops.text.save('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    bpy.context.area.type = area_type
```

However, when executing the line `bpy.ops.text.save()`, the following error occurs:

```
File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 188, in \_\_call\_\_

ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.text.save.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

I expect I must better specify the context for `bpy.ops.text.save`. Any hints, advice, or a solution would be very welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### About 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'  and context override

While you can often override a context [not all operators support it](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/info_gotcha.html?highlight=gotcha).

Examples of [context overrides](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=context+override), in particular this one: [context override in text editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8444/47), see also [a more extensive explanation of context overriding](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/47). Avoid doing this whenever possible, there is in this case an alternative.

#### A more sane alternative.

I recommend that you spawn your own file save dialog - a template for that code exists. See *Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator File Export*

To save a Text Datablock to disk is easy.

```
destination = '/home/zeffii/Desktop/file.txt'

text_reference = bpy.data.texts['Text']
with open(destination, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(text_reference.as_string())
```

Comment: Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator File Export => Perfect Answer! Thank you.