# I got "RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode.poll() failed, context is incorrect"

Tags: python

I would like to use [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8435/how-to-programmatically-load-a-python-script-in-text-editor-and-launch-it/31398#31398), but I totally stucked.

A.py

```
myPath=r"C:\tem\B.py"

text = bpy.data.texts.load(myPath) 

ctx = bpy.context.copy()
ctx['edit_text'] = text
bpy.ops.text.run_script(ctx)
```

B.py

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="FACE")
```

When I call A.py, `bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="FACE")` say,
"RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode.poll() failed, context is incorrect"

When I call B.py from text editor directly, it is fine.
So, I'm really confusing.

---Edit and add explanation--------------------

When the object is "object mode", I run B.py directly and it run correct.
When the same situation, I run A.py to run B.py,
B.py say, "bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode.poll() failed".

B.py has bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') difinitely, and changed the select mode correctly. But the "mesh.select_mode" is failed, if B.py is called from A.py.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When the object is "object mode", I run B.py directly and it run correct. 
When the same situation,  I run A.py to run B.py, B.py say, "bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode.poll()  failed".

B.py has `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')` difinitely, and changed the select mode correctly.
But the "mesh.select_mode" is failed, if B.py is called from A.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the linked question is from 2015 and the method to [overwrite a context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override) just changed with Blender 3.3.

In Blender 3.3, you have to change the last three lines of *A.py* to

```
import bpy

myPath=r"C:\tem\B.py"

text = bpy.data.texts.load(myPath) 

with bpy.context.temp_override(edit_text=text):
    bpy.ops.text.run_script()
```

Comment: I update my blender 3.1->3.3 and your script and B.py goes fine.
Thank you! 
(I don't know actually, but I feel 3.1 had a bit weird action)